# Apple developer account

Tags: ios

The new iOS simulator stinks.

I Wanted to test on my iPod that is plugged up to x code; i receive the error.

No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “iPhone Developer” were found.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.

Is paying for the dev program the only way to test on a specific device or is there a way around it for now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a paid developer account is the only way, unless you jailbreak the device.

Comment: thanks.... -7 for my post. yikes. if this were golf id be in first...by the way i meant virtual iPod (i.e. iOS simulator) not physically